# Current amplifier (current in current out) for photo diode with modulated light

Tags: current, amplifier

I have a device which contains a photodiode. To work in lower light conditions, I want to add a current amplifier circuit between the photodiode and the rest of the circuit. I could not find photodiodes with greater responsivity and I am not allowed to change the rest of the circuit, so I can only amplify the current from the photodiode. The photodiode current I can expect is about 1μA and I would like to amplify this to get 10μA.
The light hitting the photodiode can be modulated to 50kHz and the current output by the amplification stage should not be distorted.
Voltage amplifiers appear to be very common however I am unable to find current amplifiers that output a current. Are there devices that I can buy off the shelf that are able to do this?

Comment: Have you checked using a transimpedance  amplifier with a voltage-to-current opamp circuit?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @TrapLevel. I have not but that is a good suggestion.

Comment: A plain BJT would do a half-decent job, though it may not be linear enough.